# C++ namespaces, inner classes and operator resolution

Tags: c++, namespaces, global, operator-keyword

In the C++ namespace `myspace` I have a class `Outer` which in turn has an inner class `Inner`. While I can declare and define a global friend operator `QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& s, const myspace::Outer& o)`, I cannot see how to declare a global friend operator `QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& s, const myspace::Outer::Inner& o)`. The commented out lines represent a failed attempt. I do not see how to declare the inner class without defining the outer.

```
namespace myspace {
    class Outer;
    //class Outer::Inner;
}

QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& s, const myspace::Outer& o);
//QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& s, const myspace::Outer::Inner& o);


namespace myspace {

    class Outer {

        friend QDataStream& (::operator <<)(QDataStream&, const Outer&);

        class Inner {
            //friend QDataStream& (::operator <<)(QDataStream&, const Inner&);
            int i;
        };

        int o;
    };

}
```

I have read
[Namespaces and operator resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195512/namespaces-and-operator-resolution), [C++ Defining the << operator of an inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109170/c-defining-the-operator-of-an-inner-class), [Accessing private class in operator<< in namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310922/accessing-private-class-in-operator-in-namespace)
and [Operator overloading, name resolution and namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329694/operator-overloading-name-resolution-and-namespaces), but none seem to work.

If I uncomment these lines, the first gives the error message "outer.h:7: error: 'Inner' in 'class myspace::Outer' does not name a type
     class Outer::Inner;
                  ^"
This seems to be the key. I cannot declare the inner class.

I am using C++ 11.

This question is not a duplicate of [Forward declaration of nested types/classes in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951234/forward-declaration-of-nested-types-classes-in-c) if it can can be solved without forward reference.

Comment: Can you add error messages you get when you try to compile with the failed attempts ?

Comment: I added the error message when the first commented line is uncommented.

Comment: You are correct, this is a duplicate. It seems it is impossible in C++.

Comment: *This is not a duplicate - not forward declaration needed*

There is a simple solution which I cannot add because of the duplicate mark:

namespace myspace
{
 class Outer
 {
  friend QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream&, const Outer&);

 public:
  class Inner
  {
   friend QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream&, const Inner&);
   int i;
  };

 private:
  int o;
 };

 QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& s, const myspace::Outer& o)
 {
  s << o.o;
  return s;
 }

 QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& s, const myspace::Outer::Inner& i)
 {
  s << i.i;
  return s;
 }
}

Comment: @AndreasH you need to make the Inner class `public`. It is `private` in the original contents. There is no solution in this case. But I agree, it is not an exact duplicate.

Comment: You do not have to make the inner class public. You can also make operator<<(QDataStream& s, const myspace::Outer::Inner& i) a friend for the Outer and the Inner class. This way the operator definition works without making Inner a public type.

Comment: try this (no public keyword and perfectly working): `namespace myspace
{
 class Outer
 {
  class Inner
  {
   friend QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream&, const Inner&);
   int i;
  };

  friend QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream&, const Outer&);
  friend QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream&, const Inner&);

  int o;
 };

 QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& s, const myspace::Outer& o)
 {
  s << o.o;
  return s;
 }

 QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& s, const myspace::Outer::Inner& i)
 {
  s << i.i;
  return s;
 }
}`

Comment: Thank you Andreas H. Your solution works perfectly. I panicked when the Duplicate was thrown at me, since I could not see a non forward reference approach. I will re-ask the question, since the problem is real and you solved it.

Comment: Yes AndreasH. Your solution works! Thank you. I was on the verge of de-encapsulating!

Comment: Reopened @AndreasH.

Answer (score 0):

Given the time lapse, I am posting the correct answer given by Andreas H.

```
namespace myspace {
class Outer {
    class Inner {
        friend QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream&, const Inner&);
        int i;
    };
    friend QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream&, const Outer&);
    friend QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream&, const Inner&);
    int o;
};
QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& s, const myspace::Outer& o) {
    s << o.o;
    return s;
}
QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& s, const myspace::Outer::Inner& i) {
    s << i.i;
    return s;
}
}
```